# Method of Frobenius, why take the derivative with respect to r?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, frobenius-method

Here's the link explaining the method of Frobenius with a double root I am referring to:
http://www.creighton.edu/fileadmin/user/CCAS/departments/Math/docs/DE/series_solutions/Equal_Roots_Example.pdf

Why do they take $\frac{\text{d}a_n}{\text{d}r}$? How does this guarantee the solution they find will actually work?

Comment: Because $r=-1$ is a repeated zero. See, for instance, Boyce & Di-Prima (Chapter5), or http://www.iitg.ac.in/shyamashree/Lecture15-2016.pdf

Comment: But why do you take the derivative with respect to $r$? Why would that be useful? Why not just introduce another variable $s$ for no reason at all and then take a derivative with respect to $s$? How is that different from taking the derivative with respect to $r$?